# Parse file length to user friendly format

Tags: c#, windows, fileinfo

I am using the following in C# to get the length of a file

```
long length = new System.IO.FileInfo(path).Length;
```

How can I nicely parse the file into same as Windows displays it:

> 2.92 MB (3,072,000 bytes)

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in. But you can 1)find the order of magnitude, 2)divide, 3)format to two decimal places, and 4)stick the prefix onto the unit. Aaaaaaand...there's a duplicate. Of course.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("{0:##0.00} ({1:#,###} bytes)", volume / (1024.0 * 1024.0), volume);`

Comment: A quick way is to use the [Humanizer](https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer) NuGet package: `fileSize.Bytes().ToString("#.##")` will give the desired result.

Comment: FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
                float byteLength = (fi.Length / 1024f) / 1024f;
                String outputString = byteLength.ToString("0.##") + " MB (" + fi.Length + " bytes)";